# Automatic Link two different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have been trying to find a solution for this issue for quite some time, but haven't been able to do so without excel VBA, so here goes:

I currently have two workbooks saved in the company's database (shared documents). For this example, I will name them "Target.xlsx" and "Main.xlsx".

The "Main" workbook is a calculation workbook, and "Target" is a database workbook.

The "Main" workbook remains open throughout the day, and only I use it, so it only stays open in my machine.
The "Target" workbook gets opened whenever someone sends a request from another workbook, which opens the "Target" workbook (through VBA) and record the request in the workbook, saves and closes it.

What I want to happen is: whenever someone records new information in the "Target" workbook, I want the "Main" workbook to get updated without the need for me to press the "update links" section in excel. Is there any way to do it?

I wonder if a power query would do the trick? If so, how?

Comment: You want to do it *without* VBA?   It would be simple enough using VBA and `OnTime`...